# Channel:mychannel received discovery error:access denied

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-caliper

I'm new to Hyperledger and trying to use Hyperledger Caliper v0.3.2 as benchmark tool to test Fabric v1.3. I followed two official tutorials: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/build_network.html and https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/v0.3.2/fabric-tutorial/tutorials-fabric-existing/

Now I have successfully instantiated `fabcar` chaincode and the query is successful in `peer0.org1` as follows

```
peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n fabcar -c '{"Args":["queryAllCars"]}'
```

However when I run caliper, it gives me error `[Channel.js]: Channel:mychannel received discovery error:access denied` and details are as follows:

```
2021-03-17T10:34:45.736Z - error: [Channel.js]: Channel:mychannel received discovery error:access denied
2021-03-17T10:34:45.737Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: Channel:mychannel Discovery error:access denied
2021-03-17T10:34:45.737Z - error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: Channel:mychannel Discovery error:access denied
2021.03.17-18:34:45.737 info  [caliper] [caliper-local-client]  Client[1] encountered an error during prepare test phase: Error: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: Channel:mychannel Discovery error:access denied
    at Network._initializeInternalChannel (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/network.js:119:12)
    at <anonymous>
2021.03.17-18:34:45.738 info  [caliper] [caliper-local-client]  Info: client 1 prepare test :Template callbackphase complete
2021.03.17-18:34:45.739 error [caliper] [round-orchestrator]    Failed round 1 (queryAsset): Error: Error: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: Channel:mychannel Discovery error:access denied
    at WorkerOrchestrator.updateWorkerPhase (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-cli/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-core/lib/master/orchestrators/worker-orchestrator.js:211:61)
    at WorkerOrchestrator.processWorkerUpdate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-cli/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-core/lib/master/orchestrators/worker-orchestrator.js:124:18)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-cli/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-core/lib/common/messaging/process-master.js:51:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:772:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:141:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
2021.03.17-18:34:45.739 info  [caliper] [report-builder]    ### All test results ###
2021.03.17-18:34:45.740 error [caliper] [report-builder]    No data within test result; implies error within configuration files
2021.03.17-18:34:45.740 error [caliper] [round-orchestrator]    Error while finalizing the report: Error: unrecognized report table
    at ReportBuilder.setSummaryTable (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-cli/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-core/lib/master/report/report-builder.js:142:19)
    at Report.printResultsByRound (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-cli/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-core/lib/master/report/report.js:254:28)
    at RoundOrchestrator.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-cli/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-core/lib/master/orchestrators/round-orchestrator.js:221:25)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
2021.03.17-18:34:45.741 info  [caliper] [monitor.js]    Stopping all monitors
2021.03.17-18:34:45.741 info  [caliper] [worker-orchestrator]   Sending exit message to connected workers
2021.03.17-18:34:45.741 info  [caliper] [round-orchestrator]    Benchmark finished in 7.58 seconds. Total rounds: 1. Successful rounds: 0. Failed rounds: 1.
2021.03.17-18:34:45.741 info  [caliper] [caliper-engine]    Skipping end command due to benchmark flow conditioning
2021.03.17-18:34:45.742 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-master]     Benchmark successfully finished
2021.03.17-18:34:45.743 error [caliper] [message-handler]   Handled unsuccessful "prepare" message for worker 1 and test round 0 with error Error: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: Channel:mychannel Discovery error:access denied
    at Network._initializeInternalChannel (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/network.js:119:12)
    at <anonymous>
2021.03.17-18:34:45.743 info  [caliper] [message-handler]   Handling "exit" message
2021.03.17-18:34:45.743 info  [caliper] [message-handler]   Handled "exit" message for worker 1, exiting process
zch@zch:~/go/src/caliper-workspace$ 2021.03.17-18:34:45.793 info  [caliper] [message-handler]   Handling "exit" message
2021.03.17-18:34:45.794 info  [caliper] [message-handler]   Handled "exit" message for worker 0, exiting process
```

I built the network with `my-config.yaml` using `./byfn.sh generate -f my-config.yaml` and `./byfn.sh up -f my-config.yaml`:

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer.example.com:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
  peer1.org1.example.com:
  peer0.org2.example.com:
  peer1.org2.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:
services:
  ca0:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      # change the corresponding sk file name! {hash}_sk -> CA1_PRIVATE_KEY
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/CA1_PRIVATE_KEY
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/CA1_PRIVATE_KEY -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_peerOrg1
    networks:
      - byfn

  ca1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org2
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
      # change the corresponding sk file name! {hash}_sk -> CA2_PRIVATE_KEY
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/CA2_PRIVATE_KEY
    ports:
      - "8054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/CA2_PRIVATE_KEY -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_peerOrg2
    networks:
      - byfn

  orderer.example.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: orderer.example.com
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
    environment:
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
    environment:
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
    environment:
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
    environment:
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
    environment:
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - peer0.org1.example.com
      - peer1.org1.example.com
      - peer0.org2.example.com
      - peer1.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

and the docker status is like below after I deploy `fabcar` manually:

```
zch@zch:~/go/src/fabric-samples/first-network$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                                                                    COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                              NAMES
4fcb496b031f   dev-peer0.org1.example.com-fabcar-1.0-5c906e402ed29f20260ae42283216aa75549c571e2e380f3615826365d8269ba   "chaincode -peer.add…"   14 minutes ago   Up 14 minutes                                                      dev-peer0.org1.example.com-fabcar-1.0
d10866fc9da4   dev-peer0.org2.example.com-fabcar-1.0-264b0a1cb5efbecaac5cf8990339c24474dc8435c6e10f10f2be565d555d0e94   "chaincode -peer.add…"   14 minutes ago   Up 14 minutes                                                      dev-peer0.org2.example.com-fabcar-1.0
da7d865f96f6   dev-peer1.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0-26c2ef32838554aac4f7ad6f100aca865e87959c9a126e86d764c8d01f8346ab     "chaincode -peer.add…"   16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes                                                      dev-peer1.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0
1a3f4cca5662   dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-1.0-384f11f484b9302df90b453200cfb25174305fce8f53f4e94d45ee3b6cab0ce9     "chaincode -peer.add…"   16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes                                                      dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-1.0
e7c307b3adfc   dev-peer0.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0-15b571b3ce849066b7ec74497da3b27e54e0df1345daff3951b94245ce09c42b     "chaincode -peer.add…"   16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes                                                      dev-peer0.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0
c288f83482b5   hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest                                                                          "/bin/bash"              17 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes                                                      cli
3f49cc3ff53d   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest                                                                           "peer node start"        17 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes   0.0.0.0:10051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10053->7053/tcp   peer1.org2.example.com
986e2c96a8e7   hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest                                                                             "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   17 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes   0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                             ca_peerOrg1
b64e2b93d37f   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest                                                                           "peer node start"        17 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes   0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp     peer0.org1.example.com
befd47bd74be   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest                                                                           "peer node start"        17 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes   0.0.0.0:8051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8053->7053/tcp     peer1.org1.example.com
550b37ba6cf7   hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest                                                                             "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   17 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes   0.0.0.0:8054->7054/tcp                             ca_peerOrg2
167406b02860   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest                                                                           "peer node start"        17 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes   0.0.0.0:9051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9053->7053/tcp     peer0.org2.example.com
8cb72ecb0c9a   hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest                                                                        "orderer"                17 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes   0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                             orderer.example.com
```

I think it may be some config error. So I paste my `network_config.json` here:

```
{
    "caliper": {
        "blockchain": "fabric"
    },
    "clients": {
        "Admin@org1.example.com": {
            "client": {
                "credentialStore": {
                    "path": "tmp/hfc-kvs/org1",
                    "cryptoStore": {
                        "path": "tmp/hfc-kvs/org1"
                    }
                },
                "organization": "Org1",
                "clientPrivateKey": {
                    "path": "../fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/key.pem"
                },
                "clientSignedCert": {
                    "path": "../fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem"
                },
                "connection": {
                    "timeout": {
                        "peer": {
                            "endorser": "300"
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    },
    "channels": {
        "mychannel": {
            "created" : true,
            "chaincodes": [
                {
                    "id":"fabcar",
                    "version":"1.0"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "name": "test-network-org1",
    "organizations":{
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org1.example.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.org1.example.com"
            ],
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "../fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/key.pem"
            },
            "signedCert": {
                "path": "../fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem"
            }
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path":"../fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com",
                "hostnameOverride": "peer0.org1.example.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "https://localhost:7054",
            "caName": "ca-org1",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path":"../fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
            },
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
        }
    },
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

my `crypto-congig` directory:

```
zch@zch:~/go/src/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config$ tree
.
├── ordererOrganizations
│   └── example.com
│       ├── ca
│       │   ├── ca.example.com-cert.pem
│       │   └── key.pem
│       ├── msp
│       │   ├── admincerts
│       │   │   └── Admin@example.com-cert.pem
│       │   ├── cacerts
│       │   │   └── ca.example.com-cert.pem
│       │   └── tlscacerts
│       │       └── tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
│       ├── orderers
│       │   └── orderer.example.com
│       │       ├── msp
│       │       │   ├── admincerts
│       │       │   │   └── Admin@example.com-cert.pem
│       │       │   ├── cacerts
│       │       │   │   └── ca.example.com-cert.pem
│       │       │   ├── keystore
│       │       │   │   └── key.pem
│       │       │   ├── signcerts
│       │       │   │   └── orderer.example.com-cert.pem
│       │       │   └── tlscacerts
│       │       │       └── tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
│       │       └── tls
│       │           ├── ca.crt
│       │           ├── server.crt
│       │           └── server.key
│       ├── tlsca
│       │   ├── key.pem
│       │   └── tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
│       └── users
│           └── Admin@example.com
│               ├── msp
│               │   ├── admincerts
│               │   │   └── Admin@example.com-cert.pem
│               │   ├── cacerts
│               │   │   └── ca.example.com-cert.pem
│               │   ├── keystore
│               │   │   └── key.pem
│               │   ├── signcerts
│               │   │   └── Admin@example.com-cert.pem
│               │   └── tlscacerts
│               │       └── tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
│               └── tls
│                   ├── ca.crt
│                   ├── client.crt
│                   └── client.key
└── peerOrganizations
    ├── org1.example.com
    │   ├── ca
    │   │   ├── CA1_PRIVATE_KEY
    │   │   └── ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │   ├── msp
    │   │   ├── admincerts
    │   │   │   └── Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │   │   ├── cacerts
    │   │   │   └── ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │   │   ├── config.yaml
    │   │   └── tlscacerts
    │   │       └── tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │   ├── peers
    │   │   ├── peer0.org1.example.com
    │   │   │   ├── msp
    │   │   │   │   ├── admincerts
    │   │   │   │   │   └── Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │   │   │   │   ├── cacerts
    │   │   │   │   │   └── ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │   │   │   │   ├── config.yaml
    │   │   │   │   ├── keystore
    │   │   │   │   │   └── key.pem
    │   │   │   │   ├── signcerts
    │   │   │   │   │   └── peer0.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │   │   │   │   └── tlscacerts
    │   │   │   │       └── tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │   │   │   └── tls
    │   │   │       ├── ca.crt
    │   │   │       ├── server.crt
    │   │   │       └── server.key
    │   │   └── peer1.org1.example.com
    │   │       ├── msp
    │   │       │   ├── admincerts
    │   │       │   │   └── Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │   │       │   ├── cacerts
    │   │       │   │   └── ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │   │       │   ├── config.yaml
    │   │       │   ├── keystore
    │   │       │   │   └── key.pem
    │   │       │   ├── signcerts
    │   │       │   │   └── peer1.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │   │       │   └── tlscacerts
    │   │       │       └── tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │   │       └── tls
    │   │           ├── ca.crt
    │   │           ├── server.crt
    │   │           └── server.key
    │   ├── tlsca
    │   │   ├── key.pem
    │   │   └── tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │   └── users
    │       ├── Admin@org1.example.com
    │       │   ├── msp
    │       │   │   ├── admincerts
    │       │   │   │   └── Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │       │   │   ├── cacerts
    │       │   │   │   └── ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │       │   │   ├── keystore
    │       │   │   │   └── key.pem
    │       │   │   ├── signcerts
    │       │   │   │   └── Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │       │   │   └── tlscacerts
    │       │   │       └── tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │       │   └── tls
    │       │       ├── ca.crt
    │       │       ├── client.crt
    │       │       └── client.key
    │       └── User1@org1.example.com
    │           ├── msp
    │           │   ├── admincerts
    │           │   │   └── User1@org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │           │   ├── cacerts
    │           │   │   └── ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │           │   ├── keystore
    │           │   │   └── key.pem
    │           │   ├── signcerts
    │           │   │   └── User1@org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │           │   └── tlscacerts
    │           │       └── tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    │           └── tls
    │               ├── ca.crt
    │               ├── client.crt
    │               └── client.key
    └── org2.example.com
        ├── ca
        │   ├── CA2_PRIVATE_KEY
        │   └── ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
        ├── msp
        │   ├── admincerts
        │   │   └── Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem
        │   ├── cacerts
        │   │   └── ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
        │   ├── config.yaml
        │   └── tlscacerts
        │       └── tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
        ├── peers
        │   ├── peer0.org2.example.com
        │   │   ├── msp
        │   │   │   ├── admincerts
        │   │   │   │   └── Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem
        │   │   │   ├── cacerts
        │   │   │   │   └── ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
        │   │   │   ├── config.yaml
        │   │   │   ├── keystore
        │   │   │   │   └── key.pem
        │   │   │   ├── signcerts
        │   │   │   │   └── peer0.org2.example.com-cert.pem
        │   │   │   └── tlscacerts
        │   │   │       └── tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
        │   │   └── tls
        │   │       ├── ca.crt
        │   │       ├── server.crt
        │   │       └── server.key
        │   └── peer1.org2.example.com
        │       ├── msp
        │       │   ├── admincerts
        │       │   │   └── Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem
        │       │   ├── cacerts
        │       │   │   └── ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
        │       │   ├── config.yaml
        │       │   ├── keystore
        │       │   │   └── key.pem
        │       │   ├── signcerts
        │       │   │   └── peer1.org2.example.com-cert.pem
        │       │   └── tlscacerts
        │       │       └── tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
        │       └── tls
        │           ├── ca.crt
        │           ├── server.crt
        │           └── server.key
        ├── tlsca
        │   ├── key.pem
        │   └── tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
        └── users
            ├── Admin@org2.example.com
            │   ├── msp
            │   │   ├── admincerts
            │   │   │   └── Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem
            │   │   ├── cacerts
            │   │   │   └── ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
            │   │   ├── keystore
            │   │   │   └── key.pem
            │   │   ├── signcerts
            │   │   │   └── Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem
            │   │   └── tlscacerts
            │   │       └── tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
            │   └── tls
            │       ├── ca.crt
            │       ├── client.crt
            │       └── client.key
            └── User1@org2.example.com
                ├── msp
                │   ├── admincerts
                │   │   └── User1@org2.example.com-cert.pem
                │   ├── cacerts
                │   │   └── ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
                │   ├── keystore
                │   │   └── key.pem
                │   ├── signcerts
                │   │   └── User1@org2.example.com-cert.pem
                │   └── tlscacerts
                │       └── tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
                └── tls
                    ├── ca.crt
                    ├── client.crt
                    └── client.key

109 directories, 107 files
```

Are my configuration correct? Especially the two `tlsCACerts`? Hope you guys can point out where I'm wrong, or instruct me to find specific errors. I'll appreciate that.

Comment: 1) look if u already ve wallet folder(dont look like), if u ve, delete it
2) be care about ports
3)be care about paths

Comment: @LuisBote Thanks for your comment. I'm sure I didn't use wallet, however, I'm not sure about the ports and paths, especially two `tlsCACerts` paths in `certificateAuthorities` and `peers` :( So could you please point out wheter my config is correct based on the tree of `crypto-config`? Thank you in advance

Comment: 1)Where its your network_config.json located
2) Did u change something on configs files?
3)Can u bring us your commnads steps to wake up your blockchain?
@zch

Comment: @LuisBote 1) the file is in `networks/network_config.json` 2) I copied form https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/v0.3.2/fabric-tutorial/tutorials-fabric-existing/#step-3---network-configuration-file changed the certificates' location and chaincode's version. I didn't change other settings. 3) I use this command to bring up caliper test `caliper launch master --caliper-benchconfig benchmarks/myAssetBenchmark.yaml --caliper-networkconfig networks/network_config.json --caliper-workspace ./ --caliper-flow-only-test --caliper-fabric-gateway-usegateway --caliper-fabric-gateway-discovery`

Comment: @LuisBote As for bring up the fabric network, I use `./byfn.sh up -f my-config.yaml` as I mentioned in the question. The I wrote a bash script to setup `fabcar` chaincode, which can be found in https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZHSthCmg9Q/

Comment: I checked the logs in my peer0.org1 container, There are two types of errors: 1)`ERRO 0a4 TLS handshake failed with error EOF {"server": "PeerServer", "remote address": "172.21.0.1:48624"}` 2) `ERRO 0a5 Principal deserialization failure (the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.org1.example.com")) for identity ...`

Comment: That its getting me some ideas, you can invoke but u cant querys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem.
I created several Fabric networks, however, the path `<caliper-workspace>/tmp` stores the earliest crypto configs, so it reports `access denied` error. To solve it, remove `<caliper-workspace>/tmp` everytime you run the caliper

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
    export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:7051
```

edit 1:

As you post error and your sh code, look like peer adrees its badly, so export it to your peer adrees, in your case, 7051

edit 2:
Why are u running builds on sudo and server without sudo? this would be probelm, try to run both without sudo, if u cant run without sudo cause u havent acces denied, run:

```
sudo chmod +x *
```

You can change it to *.sh or some like that for not grants permissions to all your files

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. When and where to `export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:7051`? Before I `./byfn.sh up -f my-config.yaml` or `caliper launch master --caliper-benchconfig benchmarks/myAssetBenchmark.yaml --caliper-networkconfig networks/network_config.json --caliper-workspace ./ --caliper-flow-only-test --caliper-fabric-gateway-usegateway --caliper-fabric-gateway-discovery`?

Comment: Is there any possible to contact you and we can communicate in real-time?

Comment: Use it before all on your console, to get that var, im not secure that your problem, but could be, try and paste output there

Comment: This shows whole procedure of 1)generate crypto material 2)bring up fabric network 3)deploy `fabcar` chaincode 4)`cd` to caliper worksapce and begin caliper test: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cRGTKSJJT9/